# Creation of Specific Table

Tags: tables

I have some trouble creating the a table in my LateX document, do you have any suggestions on how to do it? I have the following table but I need to have a "Value" and "Relative Error" header like in the second example below (with "Relative Error" and "Variance Reduction"). Below each header, I then need "DCE" and "MDCE", how can I do this?

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Results}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c c c c}
\hline\hline
$n$ & True Value & DCE & MDCE  \\ [0.5ex]
\hline
1&50&837&970 \\
2&47&877&230 \\
3&31&25 &415 \\
4 & 35 & 144 & 2356 \\
5 & 45 & 300 & 556 \\ [1ex]
\hline
\end{tabular}
\label{table:tab1}
\end{table}
```

[image]

[image: Desired Table]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Comment: Look at package `siunitx` --- it's basically straightforward.

Comment: Thank you, I will rephrase my question. In the documentation of siunitx, I don't see the possibility of having two header rows like in the above example?

Comment: You can easily – the problem is it isn't clear *where* it should be placed, as you have only 4 columns, and no semantic difference (for us) between these columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Bernard stated above, it is not really clear how this table should look like. But I give you an example which should give you answers on how to solve everything on your own.

The first thing you are asking for are `\multicolumn`s. Nothing exotic... you can find a lot on this on our homepage here. You define the number of columns and the positioning as `l`, `c`, or `r`.

In your case, it would make sense to put a `\cline` below those mutli-column headers. I strongly recommend to use the package `booktabs` as this will help you on the spacing part (and you already got rid of the vertical lines, so you are ready to set nice tables like below...). The command is called `\cmidrule` here. You can change the shortening options, if you like. E.g. `\cmidrule(r){1-2}\cmidrule(l){3-4}`...

For the double rows, you can just put several `\midrule`s together. Two `\toprule`s would be too thick, I think. In order to keep your tables clear and free from tweaking, I have put your new definition of the "top-rule" into the preamble. If you get tired of double lines later on, just remove that part.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{caption}
\renewcommand*{\toprule}{\midrule\midrule}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
    \caption{Results}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{%
            S[table-format=1.0]
            S[table-format=2.0]
            S[table-format=3.0]
            S[table-format=4.0]
            }
        \toprule
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{Value} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Relative Error (\si{\percent})}\\
        \cmidrule(rl){1-2} \cmidrule(rl){3-4}
        $n$ & {True Value} & {DCE} & {MDCE}  \\
        \midrule
        1&50&837&970 \\
        2&47&877&230 \\
        3&31&25 &415 \\
        4 & 35 & 144 & 2356 \\
        5 & 45 & 300 & 556 \\ 
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \label{table:tab1}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for - thank you! :)

Comment: No double rules, please! `;-)` Besides, the `\midrule\midrule` method is wrong.

Comment: @egreg I've delivered what the customer wants... :-) (What would be the correct syntax for the double `\midrule` I didn't dare to search for such thing... The spacing above and below looks correct so I see no problem.

Comment: @Limbo I am glad to hear that. You are welcome. Take a look into the manual of `booktabs`! It gives good advice on the typography of tables.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi I guess that `\toprule` should be used for the first rule.

Comment: @egreg I think it looks worse. And the spacing keeps the same. @Limbo, if you want to try egregs approach, just replace my definition by `\let\oldtoprule\toprule
\renewcommand*{\toprule}{\oldtoprule\midrule[.2mm]}` The `[.2mm]` is optional. I added it in order to show that you may define your desired mid-rule width.